# Software that sniffs my internet connection and tests failed packages

Tags: monitoring, internet

Does a software exist that monitores/sniffs on my system all send packages to the internet and looks specific for failed/lost packages and then tries to trace route a few times to that destination to get to know where the packages gets lost in that connection?

Comment: And what do you do with that information? Let's assume that the packages get lost at `ipv6.de-cix.fra.de.as12306.plusline.net`. What can you do about it? I have ~60 GB traffic per month. I don't want to know how many failed connections there are in a month. Probably thousands.

Comment: A trace route will get you no where if the server is turned off.  Further, a false negative condition exists where by the destination server is up and running but decides to stop hosting said package because it is out of date or updated or etc.  Then trace route will succeed but the package still won't download.